# CakePHP 3.0 cannot get 2 items from 1 table

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In a football match i have 2 clubs "Home-Club" and "Away-Club" . I have created table "match" and "club" in MySQL. In "match" table has 2 foreign key "home_id" and "away_id". I'm using cakePHP to show list matches, match information contain names of "Home-Club" and "Away-Club". How to get name of "Home-Club" and "Away-Club" in template file ( .ctp file ). 
For now I using this code in the template file:

```
$match->club->name
```

Code in Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Club']
        ];
        $this->set('match', $this->paginate($this->Match));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['match']);
    }
```

It always show name of "Away-Club". I don't known how to get name of "Home-Club"

Please tell me how to do it

Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you have the model association defined in your model files?

Comment: Yes, I have created. Here my code in "match" table $this->belongsTo('Club', [
            'className' => 'Club',
            'foreignKey' => 'home_id',
            'propertyName' => 'home_club'
        ]); $this->belongsTo('Club', [
            'className' => 'Club',
            'foreignKey' => 'away_id',
            'propertyName' => 'away_club'
        ]);

Answer (score 4):

Problem is in definition of `belongsTo` associations. Try to redefine it this way:

```php
$this->belongsTo('HomeClub', [
    'className' => 'Club',
    'foreignKey' => 'home_id',
    'propertyName' => 'home_club'
]);
$this->belongsTo('AwayClub', [
    'className' => 'Club',
    'foreignKey' => 'away_id',
    'propertyName' => 'away_club'
]);
```

Names of *belongsTo* associations have to be unique. Now contain them in the controller

```php
// ...
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['HomeClub', 'AwayClub']
];
$this->set('matches', $this->paginate($this->Match));
```

And then in the template use

```php
<?= $match->home_club->name ?>
<?= $match->away_club->name ?>
```