# Cakephp 3.0 - Multiple relations to the same model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to make an association between two tables, accounts and transfers. In the transfers form the user should be able to select the origin account and also the destination account of the transfer. But in the page, the first list (origin account) is empty, and only the second (destination account) has the list of existent accounts.

What I need is that the origin account list shows the data also.

I already read the "Associations - Linking Tables Together" doc's page and searched for information here in stack overflow, but I'm missing something. Could you guys help? Thanks in advance.

I have tables accounts and transfers constructed as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    account_types_id INT UNSIGNED,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY user_key (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY account_types_key (account_types_id) REFERENCES account_types(id),
    UNIQUE KEY name_user(name, user_id)
);
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE transfers (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    origin_account_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    destination_account_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    value decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY user_key (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY origin_account_key (origin_account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id),
    FOREIGN KEY destination_account_key (destination_account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
);
```

And my models, as follows:

TransfersTable.php:

```
$this->belongsTo('Accounts', [
    'className' => 'Accounts',
    'foreignKey' => 'origin_account_id',
    'propertyName' => 'account',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);

$this->belongsTo('Accounts', [
    'className' => 'Accounts',
    'foreignKey' => 'destination_account_id',
    'propertyName' => 'account',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

AccountsTable.php:

```
$this->hasMany('Transfers', [
    'className' => 'Accounts', 
    'foreignKey' => 'account_id',
    'bindingKey' => 'origin_account_id'
]);

$this->hasMany('Transfers', [
    'className' => 'Accounts', 
    'foreignKey' => 'account_id',
    'bindingKey' => 'destination_account_id'
]);
```

Comment: The third example on the mentioned docs page shows how it needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks, @ndm. But that is the hasMany part of the association, that I used in the AccountsTable. But isn't it necessary to do something in the other association side, too? I mean, a belongsTo association in the TransfersTable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you plan to receive `Accounts` when querying `Transfers`, sure, then you need the `belongsTo` associations, however they suffer from exactly the same problem as your `hasMany` ones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412066/cakephp-3-0-cannot-get-2-items-from-1-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in Template/Transfers/add.ctp. It was like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('origin_account_id');
echo $this->Form->input('destination_account_id', ['options' => $accounts]);
```

And should be like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('origin_account_id', ['options' => $accounts]);
echo $this->Form->input('destination_account_id', ['options' => $accounts]);
```