# ORM: associate two models with two belongsTo ( twice )

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, belongs-to

My users model has two fields: **created_by**, **modified_by** and I want to achive something like this:

```
 $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey'   => 'created_by',
        'joinType'     => 'INNER',
        'className'    => 'Users',
        'propertyName' => 'creator'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey'   => 'modified_by',
        'joinType'     => 'INNER',
        'className'    => 'Users',
        'propertyName' => 'modifier'
    ]);
```

I expected this to work but just the last one works, **modifier** in my case

Comment: How about `propertyName => ['creator', 'modifier']` ? I am sure it will work but its worth a try.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412066/cakephp-3-0-cannot-get-2-items-from-1-table

Comment: thanks @Ray, but what is the benefit, I want two associate with two foreign keys

Comment: thanks @ndm I will have a look

Comment: I looked at the question @Ray but not worked, in fact the cakebook has an example but fot hasmany!! I dont know if this a cake issue

Comment: Hi @AymanAlkom, have you tried what ndm provided, I think that might work for you. Please see my answer. I dont know what your models are called, but I have called it Creator and modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->belongsTo('Creator', [
        'foreignKey'   => 'created_by',
        'joinType'     => 'INNER',
        'className'    => 'Users',
        'propertyName' => 'creator'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Modifier', [
        'foreignKey'   => 'modified_by',
        'joinType'     => 'INNER',
        'className'    => 'Users',
        'propertyName' => 'modifier'
    ]);
```

I dont know what your tables are called, but I have created Creator and Modifier.